# Stop all servers in one action in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I am developing with IntelliJ. In this project, I need to run 3 servers.

Is there a way to create a shortcut to :

- Stop all those servers in one click or keyboard shortcut
- Optionally, restart them.

Thanks.

Comment: @vikingsteve Maybe I was not clear. I do not want to close IntelliJ. I only want to close/restart all servers.

Comment: When I change something in the core of the app, I need to restart all servers. I do it several times in a day and I would appreciate to be able to it into one action.

Comment: Depending on how you have your build profiles set up, this is pretty straightforward.  Do you use Tomcat or some other server?  Are there servers which can't be run in the same context as others (that is, are you opposed to deploying your applications all at once)?

Comment: @Makoto You think hosting all servers in a unique tomcat? I have 2 Jettys (embedded via Maven dependencies) + GWT code server. I can replace the 2 Jetty with a tomcat but probably not the GWT code server.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle did you find a solution? I've faced the same problem :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I stop all processes in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212930/how-can-i-stop-all-processes-in-intellij)

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a direct method to do this in IntelliJ, but if you can stop each one from a script, then you could just write a script and run it from IntelliJ. Personally, I'd just go to the terminal and run the script rather than configuring it directly in IntelliJ (which also has an embedded terminal, btw).