# How can I stop all processes at once in IntelliJ like in Eclipse

Tags: java, intellij-idea

There is an explanation how I can stop one process:

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/stopping-and-pausing-applications.html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075093/stop-all-servers-in-one-action-in-intellij , that poses a similar question (with a similar answer)

Comment: @AshutoshJindal Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't allows you to open multiple projects simultaneously in same window. of course you can open mupltiple projects simultaneously, each one in a separate window. So there is no need to stop all processes, so Intelli IDEA doesn't provide this feature.

In Eclipse we can open multiple projects is same windows and there is "Terminate/Disconnect All" option to stop all processes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have been more precise. You can have several processes running when you are debugging JUnit tests. Sometimes you forget to stop a debug process so it would be quite useful to have an all stop button. But as you said it seems like there isn't one.

Comment: A single _project_ can have multiple _processes_.  They are orthogonal concepts.