# How can I stop all processes in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I am using intelliJ IDEA.

When I run my programs and close the window, the process still remains. If I run a lot of programs, I need to click disconnect many times.

Is there any way to stop all processes?

Eclipse doesn't have this problem.

[image: PNG1]

[image: PNG2]

Comment: Is the "setDefaultCloseOperation()" present in the Swing applications?

Answer (score 11):

IntelliJ 2017.2 now has a "Stop All" button in the "Stop process" menu (the button on the top bar), with the default shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> on Mac OS:

[image: screenshot]

For older versions:

1. Click the Stop button from the top bar.  It will pop open a menu listing all processes.  (The stop button at the side of the debug window is per-process, as in your screenshot.)
2. Hover over the first process, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and then click on the last process.
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Screenshot showing the result of steps 1 & 2:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Command F2 is  "Stop" not "Stop All" - at least on `2018.2` on macOS. I have many many bg processes that should die but do not.

Comment: For _background_ processes, the default shortcut is Shift+⌘+F2.

Comment: This isn't working for "zombie" processes which were started by IntelliJ but not cancelled.

Comment: @ThreeCheeseHigh That's unfortunate -- sounds like a bug you should report to JetBrains!

Answer (score 8):

```
kill $(ps aux | grep 'java' | awk '{print $2}')
```

This is a nice little workaround I found on SO a while ago that will kill any process with "java" in the name.

Just copy and paste into the terminal.

Comment: I usually get the complain `kill: kill (some number) failed: no such process` but even when I get that, the processes still stop

Comment: when i paste it,i get kill is command or external command,
Not recognized as operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Ives try inputting that command into Cygwin if you're using Windows.

Comment: nice solution, but running `kill $(ps aux | grep 'java' | awk '{print $2}')` as an external tool in intellij results in permission errors.

Comment: works as an 'external tool' if you put it is a bash file, and chmod a+x the bash file.

Comment: Simpler: `pkill java` (or `pkill '.*java.*'` to match this "contains" behavior).

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly perfect, but what you could do is press Ctrl + F2 (shortcut for Stop Process) and hit Enter. It's better than all that mouse clicking and gets you through a list of running processes quite fast.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a script like `killJavaProcess` and invoke it in `Before launch` section as `External tool`

[image: Before launch section]

For example `~/.bin/killonport`

```
#!/bin/zsh

function help() {
  echo "usage: killonport port"
  echo "-f don't ask before killing"
  echo "-h help"
}

function killListenerOnPort() {
  # get script options
  zparseopts -E -D h=HELP f=FORCE

  [[ -n $HELP ]] &&
    help &&
    return

  local PORT
  PORT=$1

  [[ -z "$PORT" ]] &&
    help &&
    return

  local LISTEN
  # find process listening on port with lsof
  LISTEN="$(lsof -nP -iTCP:"$PORT" -sTCP:LISTEN)"

  local PROCESS
  # remove first line of output lsof
  PROCESS="$(echo "$LISTEN" | tail -n +2)"

  local HEAD
  # get first line of output lsof
  HEAD="$(echo "$LISTEN" | head -n 1)"

  [[ -z $PROCESS ]] &&
    echo "Process not found" &&
    return

  local COUNT
  # assure that found only one process else printing founded processes and exit
  COUNT=$(echo "$PROCESS" | wc -l | xargs)
  [[ $COUNT -gt 1 ]] &&
    printf 'Found more then one process: %s\n%s\n%s\n' "$COUNT" "$HEAD" "$PROCESS" &&
    return

  # get name and PID
  local NAME
  NAME=$(echo "$PROCESS" | awk '{print $1}')
  local PID
  PID=$(echo "$PROCESS" | awk '{print $2}')

  # if -f option specified kill silently
  [[ -n "$FORCE" ]] &&
    kill -9 "$PID" &&
    return

  # ask confirmation to kill
  echo "Kill process '$NAME' with PID '$PID'"
  read -qr 'REPL?Continue? (y/n) '
  echo

  # kill if confirmed
  [[ $REPL == 'y' || $REPL == 'Y' ]] &&
    kill -9 "$PID"
}

killListenerOnPort "$@"
```